# SVM from e1071 R package replaces labels if there is a feature with only 1 unique value

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

Why SVM from `e1071` package replaces original labels by "1" and "2", if there is at least one such column having only one unique value?

For example, the code below works correctly:

```
  trainData <- data.frame("cA" = c(1, 1, 1, 0.99),
                          "cB" = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3), 
                          "is_match" = factor(c("N", "N", "P", "P")))
  testData <- data.frame("cA" = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
                         "cB" = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1))

  model <- svm(is_match ~ ., data = trainData, type = "C-classification")
  pred <- predict(model, testData, type = "class")
  print(pred)
```

it returns

```
1 2 3 4 
P P P P
```

However, if I change 0.99 to 1 in the first column - so that all values become the same - svm changes labels "N" and "P" to "1" and "2":

```
  trainData <- data.frame("cA" = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                          "cB" = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3), 
                          "is_match" = factor(c("N", "N", "P", "P")))
  testData <- data.frame("cA" = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
                         "cB" = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1))

  model <- svm(is_match ~ ., data = trainData, type = "C-classification")
  pred <- predict(model, testData, type = "class")
  print(pred)
```

Such code returns:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 2 2 2
```

Additional notes:

- It happens with all possible values in column (zeros, NAs) as long as they are all the same for each instance
- if labels are digits, `svm` doesn't replace them
- other ML methods like `rpart` or `ada` works correctly